# Using VSCode with WSL, run button does not run with mnt. Hence, my code is not found to run

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using WSL ubuntu on a windows computer while using VSCode as my code editor.

I'm trying to run python files on WSL but when pressing on the run button (https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5DfM.png) (ctrl + alt + n) the code gets executed with the default windows explorer pathway (c:\users...) so that makes my file not readable for WSL to run.

Here is a screenshot on what it seems like:

[Screenshot of the shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SkjX.png)

As you can see, when I press on the run button it comes with the error:

```
python: can't open file 'c:\Users\name\Desktop\firstone\newfolder\base.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Because it is coming in the format of c:\Users...

Meanwhile when I run a command that I typed on my own of the correct format:

```
python -u /mnt/c/Users/name/Desktop/firstone/newfolder/base.py
```

It works correctly.

Do you know how I can automatically map the run button to run for a wsl environment?

I would really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: `Run Code` (ctrl + alt + n) is provided by the third-party extension **Code Runner**. Why not use the `Run Python File` provided by the official extension? https://imgur.com/PuZrOjW

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for anyone what is wondering later.

Follow the instructions on this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/python/web-frameworks

The most important part is to initiate the "Run Python File in Terminal" first before pressing the run button.